# Please tell me the disease/issue with my mint plant

Tags: diseases, mint

These mint leaves are pale yellow-green. Please tell me what is wrong with them with all the discoloured appearance.

Pot-12~14 inch

Soil mix-Old vermicompost~vermiculite~perlite mixed with about 20 percent garden soil.

No fertiliser added. Watered using drinking water.

[image]